# Show android notification every five minutes

Tags: android, notifications

I want to know how to set time for notification. I want to set notification every five minutes,
so help me do that.

```
public class FirstActivity extends Activity
{
    private static final int HELLO_ID = 1;
    //public static final int FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL = 0;`enter code here`
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.firstactivity);

        String ns = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(ns);

        int icon = R.drawable.icon;
        CharSequence tickerText = "Hello";
        long when = System.currentTimeMillis();

        Notification notification = new Notification(icon, tickerText, when);

        RemoteViews contentView = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.statusbarnotification);
        contentView.setImageViewResource(R.id.image, R.drawable.icon);
        contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.text, "Hello, this message is in a custom expanded view");
        notification.contentView = contentView;
        notification.flags = Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS | Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SecondActivity.class);
        //PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
        notification.contentIntent = contentIntent;
        mNotificationManager.notify(HELLO_ID, notification);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

I think that the best way will be to create a service that sets the notification and then activate the service using AlarmManager.
That's the code for the AlarmManager:

```
private void startAlarm() {
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) this.getSystemService(this.ALARM_SERVICE);
    long when = System.currentTimeMillis();         // notification time
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ReminderService.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, intent, 0);
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, when, (AlarmManager.INTERVAL_FIFTEEN_MINUTES / 3), pendingIntent);
}
```

To control the interval use the constant values or just insert your own value (in milliseconds).

Here is the Service:

```
public class ReminderService extends IntentService {
    private static final int NOTIF_ID = 1;

    public ReminderService(){
        super("ReminderService");
    }

    @Override
      protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        long when = System.currentTimeMillis();         // notification time
        Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.icon, "reminder", when);
        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
        notification.flags |= notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, YourActivity.class);
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent , 0);
        notification.setLatestEventInfo(getApplicationContext(), "It's about time", "You should open the app now", contentIntent);
        nm.notify(NOTIF_ID, notification);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks is kinda of what I wanted, but I have a question for you about this. How do I set the `AlarmManager` inside the Service Class so that when it checks the database and has new stuff to then show the notification? (If you can explain in code would be better, no need for the code of the database... only the AlarmManager inside the Service Class with the `if` statement)

Comment: When `StartAlarm()` called?? I'm not getting any notification .. code is not workin g:(