# How to show android notification after every 48hours?

Tags: android, android-layout, notifications, push-notification

I tried following code for android notification which is working fine but it is giving me notification popup when I start my android app.

> I want to show an notification after every 48hours, how can I do it?

What changes do I need to make in order for this to work?

Notification code

```
 Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Activity.class);
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(MainActivity.this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

         NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) MainActivity.this
                    .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

         Notification noti = new NotificationCompat.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                            .setTicker("ticker message")

                            .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                            .setContentTitle("HELLO")
                            .setContentText("PLEASE CHECK WE HAVE UPDATED NEWS")
                            .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
                            //At most three action buttons can be added
                            .setAutoCancel(true).build();
        int notifyID =0;
        notificationManager.notify(notifyID, noti);
```

Comment: hi go to this: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15449511/show-notification-in-every-3-sec-in-android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15449511/show-notification-in-every-3-sec-in-android)

Comment: or go to this: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7077420/show-android-notification-every-five-minutes?rq=1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7077420/show-android-notification-every-five-minutes?rq=1)

Comment: @SimplePlan both codes are not working :(

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here's something close to what you need in your main activity:

```
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, ShowNotification.class);
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, notificationIntent,
                                                           PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    am.cancel(contentIntent);
    am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis()
            + AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY * 2, AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY * 2, contentIntent);
```

Then, in another file named ShowNotification.java, add the following (assuming your main activity is named MainActivity):

```
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.util.Log;

public class ShowNotification extends Service {

    private final static String TAG = "ShowNotification";

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        Intent mainIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);

        NotificationManager notificationManager
            = (NotificationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        Notification noti = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setContentIntent(PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, mainIntent,
                              PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT))
            .setContentTitle("HELLO " + System.currentTimeMillis())
            .setContentText("PLEASE CHECK WE HAVE UPDATED NEWS")
            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setTicker("ticker message")
            .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
            .build();

        notificationManager.notify(0, noti);

        Log.i(TAG, "Notification created");
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: How to set for every one hour?

Comment: and i want to show notification whether app is open or not

Comment: The second and third arguments to the setRepeating() method specify the time of the initial alarm and the interval of subsequent alarms, respectively. The unit you'd want to use is AlarmManager.INTERVAL_HOUR. But as described in the documentation at https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setRepeating(int, long, long, android.app.PendingIntent), this approach will no longer work well for shorter durations if you're using API19 and above.

Comment: You would want to remove the "* 2" from the "AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY * 2" bits.

Answer (score 1):

doing at this way:
- Your notification will open at the starting of your activity.
- If you add a timer in, it only will appears if you have the app opened.

In your case, you should start an service, where you will have a timer that each 48 hours send a notification to Androis O.S.

For to do this loop, you will need a timmer, you can see more about services here:
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidServices/article.html

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use the AlarmManager class to schedule your notifications. Here's a snippet that should do it:

```
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
alarmManager.cancel(contentIntent);
alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                                 System.currentTimeMillis() + AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY * 2,
                                 AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY * 2,
                                 contentIntent);
```

Comment: thanks where is `Intent notificationIntent` and `Notification` code ?

Comment: and where I have to call it so that I do not get it when I launch my app only get after every 48hours

Comment: In your pending intent, you'll want to specify a separate public class that will create and execute your notification code. You can use the the same basic notification code that you already have.

Comment: thanks @scottt I'm a very new to Android dev could you please update your answer that will be greate help.

Comment: on click of that notification application is not opening?